# What does “said his bit” mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> He(Hagrid) seemed numb with shock at the verdict.
>
> "S'all my fault. Got all tongue-tied. They was all sittin' there in
>   black robes an' I kep' droppin' me notes and forgettin' all them dates
>   yeh looked up fer me, Hermione. An' then Lucius Malfoy stood up an'
>   **said his bit**, and the Committee jus' did exac'ly what he told 'em...."

Does the singular noun "bit" mean "ideas"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/say-your-piece?q=say%20%20your%20%20piece), "say one's bit" (informal) or "say one's piece" (formal) means saying something that you are obviously wanting to say.

In this case, both parties have prepared what they want to say, and take their turns to say it, so "saying their bit" simply means saying what they have prepared.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the expression "said his bit" that can be translated as "he spoke." For example, "After the wedding, the best man said his bit..." meaning he gave a speech.  There can be subtle additional meaning depending on the context.  In the wedding example, "said his bit" could be anything from a perfunctory toast to a raucous account of his mate's life or it could just mean that the details are unimportant.

As I read the excerpt you've presented, I see Lucius Malfoy giving a well prepared and eloquent speech in contrast to Hagrid who does not speak proper English and was flustered in front of the Committee.

A similar usage of the word "bit" is in comedy where a performer's routine is called a bit.